# Scene Glitching on Opening

Tags: error

I am trying to rig a model. I finish. I save the scene, just like always. Then I open it up a few hours later. The model has set its default scale to 0.17 (roughly) and shrunk to that size, the objects it has have vanished or moved, and the skeleton is rotated in a random position. I've experienced similar shrinking or movement or rotation issues basically every time I open the scene but this is the first time it's genuinely ruined work.

I'm not attaching the scene because it's an issue with all my Blender files and always has been, but now I'm done with it and I'm trying to fix this glitch.

[image]

Comment: Usually in cases like this the first thing to check if there are any keyframes in Graph editor / strips in Action editor which values differ from those you had before saving and closing the file. However if that is with all files then hard to imagine they all are keyframed. I suggest uploading the file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and putting the link in the question - after all this will allow to narrow the problem down

Comment: Okay, I added the file.